# Custom Dimension in Google Analytics Not Visible iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have integrated Google Analytics in iOS app. App is working fine and I am able to get record (screen name, event etc) on Dashboard.
But when I am trying to update data in Custom Dimension nothing gets visible. I am following below URL

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets

Below is my code for sending data to custom dimension

```
NSString *dimensionValue = [DeviceModel getDeviceName];

    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
    [tracker send:[[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] set:dimensionValue
                                                         forKey:[GAIFields customDimensionForIndex:1]] build]];
```

I added Custom dimension today in Google Analytics.

Can any one suggest me what am I doing wrong? Any idea, suggestion or tutorial would be very helpful.